# Disable button before Jquery.Validate and Enable it after JQuery.Validate method

Tags: jquery, html, .net, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3

I wanted to disable button immediately after clicking it. Currently it is taking a fraction of second to disable it due to settimeout function I believe. If I remove this, it is not working as expected. What I am thinking is, if I disable the button before validating itself, and if the validation returns false, then I wanted to enable the button again. Please help me how to disable button before the validation?

```
<div class="leftcolumn formSaveArea">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit2" class="blue button" />
```

```
jQuery("form").validate();
    if (jQuery("form").valid()) {
        setTimeout(function () { jQuery('input:submit').addClass("bluedisabled").removeClass("blue").attr("disabled","disabled"); }, 1);
    }
```

Comment: You should use a `submit` event listener, disable the button on `submit`, check if it's valid, then remove the `disabled` attribute from the button if it's invalid or after it's submitted.

Answer (score 0):

On `<form>` submit check whether form is valid or not if valid then disable submit button else dont.

Checkout this below example code:

Html :

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" /><br/>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit"  />
</form>
```

jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 //form submit 
 $("#myform").submit(function() {
    //check form is valid or not
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        //if valid do not disable
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);  
    } else {
       //if not valid disable
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
    }
 });

 //form validate 
 $("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 4
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    }
  });
});
```